# How to infer type of function parameter that is called

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I get the compiler to infer T as 'string'? It is currently infered as unknown.

```
declare function a<T>(b: (c: (d: T) => void) => void): void;

a((d) => {d('')});
```

Also tried

```
declare function a<T extends (c: <U>(d: U) => void) => void, U extends T extends (c: (d: infer I) => void) => void ? I : never>(a: T): void;

a((d) => {d('')})
```

Still same result. If I manually specify the generic and do `a<string>((d) => {d('')});`, it will restrict the d function parameter to only accept string as expected.

Comment: Don't think this is possible.

Comment: Inference doesn't generally flow that way, so I doubt this is possible.  Also, could you possibly name more things `a` so as to maximize confusion?

Comment: Fixed the naming

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understood correctly what you are trying to do, but I think that if you want to infer properly the type "string" for when you call `c` with the argument `d`, you need to adjust the position of the generic

```
declare function a(b: (c: <T>(d: T) => void) => void): void;

a((c) => {
  c("value");
});
```

Because it seems like you are interested in understand the meaning of the `c` function argument value more than the `a` function argument.

With the position of the generic modified `c`'s callable will be inferred as `c<string>`.

[image]

As the documentation says:

> Here we use type argument inference — that is, we want the compiler to set the value of Type for us automatically based **on the type of the argument we pass in**:

doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

The documentation specifies that that the inference is given by the argument from where you set the generic.

In your case, if you set the generic in `a`, the compiler will try to infer the first argument which is a function, and then off course in the next level the argument of the callable `c` will be unknown. It is easier to understand if you decouple the types

```
// The argument of C will be the type of D
type InnerFunctionC<T> = (d: T) => void;

// The argument of C will be given by the argument of B
type InnerFunctionB<T> = (c: InnerFunctionC<T>) => void;

// The argument of A will be given to B
declare function a<T>(b: InnerFunctionB<T>): void;
```

The regular inference will do the following steps

```
// A receives a function as argument the T = FN
a(
  // The FN ( b ), "pass down" the inference to "c" = FN
  (c) => { // C inferences is = FN
    c("a"); // How can typescript know C inference beforehand with T "passed down" from A ?
  }
);
```

If you want to continue with this type, the only solution is as you said, override the inference by specifying the type. ( But I see no point in doing that )

```
a<string>((d) => {d('')});
```

Hope that this helped you!

Comment: The reason I want the type to be available in FN a is because FN a takes multiple parameters, and one of the parameters is FN b which contains variable d, and another one of the parameters must be the same type as the type of d. I did use your solution (see second attempt in my question), and try to then extract that generic type via inference, but it didn't work.